# When is Memory allocated to a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructors

When is memory allocated to a constructor in a C++ program run? I think it may be when the instance(object) of the class is created or so. Is it correct?

Comment: This is likely to vary between languages and their implementations.  What specific language and implementation are you asking about?

Comment: I'm talking about c++

Comment: @SiddharthPanchal The memory is allocated with a call to a function in C++ library that is called "new". Literally, new. The function signature is void* operator new(std::size_t size). Then, after returning from that subroutine, it will call the constructor subroutine. You can test this on https://godbolt.org by compiling a simple program that creates an object instance. I just did because I was wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

A constructor is a method. As such, it takes a static amount of memory when  compiled and eventually gets called with different instances of your class. When you call a constructor function, your runtime allocates memory for an instance of your class and passes that instance to the constructor method, which  initializes the object according to its parameters.

Comment: In other words, the memory is allocated before the constructor is called.

Comment: It helped a lot

Comment: @SiddharthPanchal then you might want to accept the answer.